# Double click form event VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, double-click

I'm using VB.NET and would like to know how I can double click a form to minimize it.

I have the following code but it does'nt work:

```
Private Sub openPROJECTS_MouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDoubleClick
    'Minimize the form
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
End Sub
```

I'm using VB.NET.

Comment: do you have code in the resize event doing something? did you set a break and see if this line executes when you dbl click?  That does not look like the Form Dbl Click (args are not correct), so what is the object you want to dbl click?

Comment: That works just fine.  It rather depends on what you click on, hitting the form isn't always possible when you've covered it with other controls.  Given how unlikely it will be that the user will discover that this works by himself, it is probably best to just stick with the normal MinimizeBox on the window's title bar.

Comment: @ plutonix even if I swap the minimise windows state for a siple msgbox the doule click dosnt seam o trigger the message box either... in any case the form is not resized

Comment: if available to it, each control fires it's own doubleclick event, either add additional Handles clauses or get rid of the Handles completely and use the AddHandler statement in a foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that every control has it's own double click event, so if you double click e.g. a panel on your form, your form's double click event won't get fired.

You could, however, add a [MessageFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter.aspx), e.g.

```
Public Class Minimizer
    Implements IMessageFilter

    Private Const WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK As Integer = &H203

    ReadOnly _form As Form

    Public Sub New(f As Form)
        _form = f
    End Sub

    Public Function PreFilterMessage(ByRef m As Message) As Boolean Implements IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage
        If m.Msg = WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK Then
            _form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
        End If
        Return False
    End Function
End Class
```

And a little test:

```
Private Sub Main()
    Dim f = New Form()
    f.Controls.Add(New Panel() With { .Dock = DockStyle.Fill })
    Application.AddMessageFilter(New Minimizer(f))
    f.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

But I think it would be a strange user experience if double clicking anywhere minimizes the form...